# Adding item to list

Tags: list, elixir

I don't get it. I want to add an item to a list. But it is not working. Here my code:

```
  def put_viewed(items, user_id) do
  lll = []
  Enum.each items, fn item ->
    viewed = check_viewed(item.id, user_id)
    new_item = Map.put(item, :viewed, viewed)
    Enum.concat(lll, [new_item])
  end
  IO.inspect lll
end
```

I always get [] as result. Same with `lll ++ [new_item]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do it:

```
 def put_viewed(items, user_id) do
   Enum.reduce(items, [], fn(item, acc) ->
     viewed = check_viewed(item.id, user_id)
     new_item = Map.put(item, :viewed, viewed)
     [new_item | acc]
   end)
 end
```

You cannot mutate variables in Elixir, you gotta use functional style things, like reduction.

Comment: This one did the job. Thanks. I dived now a bit deeper into Enum.reduce, made some tutorials and understand now, how reduce works

Answer (score 4):

You can use @JustMichael answer or just use a simple Enum.map if you just need a list of processed items:

```
def put_viewed(items, user_id) do
  Enum.map(items, fn item ->
    viewed = check_viewed(item.id, user_id)
    Map.put(item, :viewed, viewed)
  end )
end
```

Comment: No need for reduction indeed!

Comment: This way I got only one element back. When items hat a count over 1 the function returned only one element.